# Google AutoML Vision API and Google Vision API Custom Algorithm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am looking at Google AutoML Vision API and Google Vision API. I know that if you use Google AutoML Vision API that it is a custom model because you train ML models based on your own images and define your own labels. And when using Google Vision API, you are using a pretrained model...

However, I am wondering if it is possible to use my own algorithm (one which I created and not provided by Google) and using that instead with Vision / AutoML Vision API ? ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can definitely deploy your own ML algorithm on Google Cloud, without being tied up to the Vision or AutoML API.

Two approaches that I have used many times for this same use case:

1. Serverless approach, if your model is relatively light in terms of computational resources requirement - Deploy your own custom cloud function. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#:%7E:text=You%20can%20deploy%20Cloud%20Functions,the%20Cloud%20Functions%20API%20directly.&text=When%20deploying%2C%20Cloud%20Functions%20looks,Writing%20Cloud%20Functions%20for%20details.).
   To be more specific, the way it works is that you just call your cloud function, passing your image directly (base64 or pointing to a storage location). The function then automatically allocates all required resources (automatically), run your custom algorithm to process the image and/or run inferences, send the results back and vanishes (all resources released, no more running costs). Neat :)
2. Google AI Platform. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models?_ga=2.2598896.-1108745508.1586534987)

> Use AI Platform to train your machine learning models at scale, to host your trained model in the cloud, and to use your model to make predictions about new data.

In doubt, go for AI Platform, as the whole pipeline is nicely lined-up for any of your custom code/models. Perfect for deployment in production as well.